# Disable mysql query unable to disable foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am using mysql and I have created two table country table and city table, country_id should be stored in city table as foreign key so I made constraint country_id in city table, but In few case I don't want to insert country _id but due to foreign key constraint I am unable to store data, so I used disable query but it is not working

Disable query for constraint

```
ALTER TABLE table_name(B)
DISABLE CONSTRAINT Name_OF_Constraint;
```

After this I f I tried to insert only city name without country_id getting error like this:

Error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`tbl`.`cities`, CONSTRAINT `cities_ibfk_1`
```

Comment: I don't think MySQL allows disabling constraints on individual basis. You'll probably need to remove it or disable foreign key checks for the whole session. What isn't clear to me is why you need this in the first place. Do you want to insert an invalid country or make the country optional?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález actually cities table already created, but due to some reason country id is kept optional but use of constraint made this impossible to have optional, so what is the process to solve this error

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac4be556cec7037cedbf3a43aafed56d). Please edit the question and include the relevant `CREATE TABLE` statements.